# How to integrate my gallery app in with the default gallery in android

Tags: android

I'm developing a small gallery application, in this application im getting images from sdcard and im displaying those images in my application and I completed this app successfully. My requirement is "When the user select some default app in the phone a chooser list is displaying, I want to add my app into that list". I have searched this in website but I couldn't get any solution for this. Please anyone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must let your application respond to a type of intents. This is done by registering an Broadcast Receiver that filters a type of intent using an intent-filter. An example is shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html. I hope that i understood your question. If not, please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Thaks for your fast response Bogdan, Can you tell me how to register an Broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

try this it is works for me,

place this intent filter in your manifest file, and menction in which activity is support that action.

```
 <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

       <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
  </intent-filter>
```